# Tomcat6 won't start on Windows and Java6

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I just downloaded a fresh copy of Tomcat6 to install on a development server. The server is running Win2k3 SP2 and Java6.

When I go to start Tomcat6 it reports the following:

```
D:\>d:\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //TS/Tomcat6
[2009-07-14 15:26:38] [427  prunsrv.c] [error] The operation completed successfully.
[2009-07-14 15:26:38] [1336 prunsrv.c] [error] Load configuration failed
```

It seems like Tomcat is having config issues, but I'm not sure where to start looking. It's a bit surprising that Tomcat had this problem right out of the box. Is there any compatability problem between Java6 and Tomcat6? Why might the default config be failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Solved this one myself. It turns out that "Load configuration failed" was a red herring. This was caused by Tomcat being unable to load java. I discovered this in $CATALINA_HOME\logs\jakarta_service_YYYMMDD.log.

I solved the problem by following these [instructions](http://vittoriop77.blogspot.com/2007/09/failed-creating-java-prunsrvc.html). Which basically amounts to copying msvcr71.dll to c:\windows\system32

Answer (score 2):

Just curious if your CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME set? Those environment variables are prerequisite to run Tomcat. Go to Start-->My Computer (right click on it) -->Properties-->Advanced-->Environment Variables (button) and then set CATALINA_HOME to the path of your Tomcat and JAVA_HOME to the location of your JDK, also add JAVA_HOME\bin to your PATH variable.

Comment: Those env vars weren't set. I tried them but got the same result:

<pre>
D:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_14

D:\>echo %CATALINA_HOME%
d:\tomcat

D:\>d:\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //TS/Tomcat6
[2009-07-14 15:57:46] [427  prunsrv.c] [error] The operation completed successfully.
[2009-07-14 15:57:46] [1336 prunsrv.c] [error] Load configuration failed
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

What would the //TS/Tomcat6 argument do?

The simplest way to make this work outside an IDE is to install it as a Windows Service and us the Monitor TOmcat application to stop and start it.

Comment: I used the //TS/Tomcat6 argument to try to get some diagnostic info. When I use the monitor app to start the service it simply fails. There is nothing notable in the activity log.